# Can I do 3D processing?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I'm working for a museum and do some programming and 3D.

The description of the exhibit I'm making reads:
"Programming and 3D processing: < My Name >"

I thought that 3d processing is what GPU does. Is it correct synonym to 3D modelling?

Comment: You are asking if the 3D modelling is a synonym for 3D processing or not?

Comment: Oops. It's a colon. I want to know if it can be user in such context or not

Comment: Why not just use "modeling"?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you worked on the exhibit in question as a programmer and 3D modeler (or similar). You are surprised that the reference to your work on the exhibit description refers to your work in "Programming and 3D **processing**", as opposed to "Programming and 3D **modeling**". And you are wondering if "Programming and 3D **processing**" is fair and accurate here. Is that correct?

If so...

In a USA work environment (where I am familiar) the 3D development portion of your job would probably be described as "3D modeler" or "3D artist". A agree that calling a person a "3D processor" would sound weird.

However, the exhibit description is not assigning you a title. It is describing the work you did. We don't have the details of this work, but I'd provide the following examples to help guide if the wording is valid:

- Generating a 3D visualization of average temperatures around the world based on the National Weather Service's data could reasonably be called 3D processing (because you have **processed** the data to produce a relatively analogous and predictable output).
- Using your own creative license to design a unique 3D logo for the exhibit would not be 3D reasonably called 3D processing. I make this claim because the question, "what was processed to produce the logo?" is unclear, where as in the above example it is very clear.